# How to get an input text value using formID?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two form on same page. There is a text field with same name in both of the forms.

I am tried to read the value of the text field from one of the two forms. if I am trying to read the value using below code i am getting the value . But I am not sure from which forms it is returning the value.

```
document.getElementById("groupId")
```

Now if I am trying to read the value from specific form using below code I am receiving the error.

```
document.forms["form1"].getElementById("groupId")
```

Please suggest whats wrong I am doing and how can we read the value of a control ?

I can use both javascript and jquery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery you could do :

```
$('[name=form_name]').find('#field_id');
```

Your case e.g :

```
$('[name=form1]').find('#groupId');
```

Using pure js you could do it like :

```
document.form_name.getElementById("field_id");
```

Sample of your case :

```
document.form1.getElementById("groupId");
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following with `jquery`.

```
var element = $(document.forms["form1"]).find('#groupId')
```

And to get the text value you can use the `val` function.

```
var text = element.val();
```

Answer (score 2):

> if i am trying to read the value using below code i am getting the value . But i am not sure from which forms it is returning the value.

This means you have multiple elements with same `id` which is a big NO. `id's` are supposed to be unique in your entire HTML. If for some reason you want to use same `id` on multiple elements to work with JavaScript be aware the same task is possible by assigning same `class` to the elements and accessing by `class`

Having said that, Change your HTML to not have duplicate `id` and change them to have a common class. Now with this structure you can access the element starting from your `from` like below

`$('form[name="form1"]').find('input.ClassName').val()`

`Also for info purpose`: If you have multiple elements with same `id` in your HTML and when you try to access by `id` the element which is placed in top parsing from top will be selected always.

Comment: Upvoted for being the only answer to point out the issue of sharing form element IDs.

Answer (score 0):

The [W3C standards for HTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html#adef-id) require the id to be unique in a document.

Comment: Thanks. i agree. Its some running messed up code i am dealing with :)

Comment: Then, you need something like: `code` document.form1.getElementById("groupId").val();